# Access: How to Combine Data from Two Rows in a Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a base dataset formatted like the one below.

```
Sex1    | Sex2    | Number|  
F       |         | 5     |   
M       |         | 8     |
M       | F       | 5     |   
F       | F       | 3     |
M       | F       | 2     |   
F       | M       | 1     |
F       | F       | 9     |   
M       | M       | 3     |
```

I'd like to use SQL to create a query that produces totals from the price by Gender composition like so:

```
Sex | Total Number
F   |    5
M   |    8
MF  |    8 
FF  |    12
MM  |    3
```

However, I'm struggling to find a way to pull the FM and MF categories into the same row. The code I have that leaves them distinct is of the form

```
SELECT Sex1 & "" & Sex2 AS Sex, Sum(Number) AS [Total Number]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Sex1 & "" & Sex2
```

Is there a simple way to combine the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` expression or the `IIf()` function to first order the two values and then group by them:

with `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Sex1 < Sex2 THEN Sex1 ELSE Sex2 END 
       & CASE WHEN Sex1 < Sex2 THEN Sex2 ELSE Sex1 END AS Sex,
       Sum(Number) AS [Total Number]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Sex1 < Sex2 THEN Sex1 ELSE Sex2 END,
         CASE WHEN Sex1 < Sex2 THEN Sex2 ELSE Sex1 END ;
```

with `IIf()` function:

```
SELECT IIf(Sex1 < Sex2, Sex1, Sex2) & IIf(Sex1 < Sex2, Sex2, Sex1) AS Sex,
       Sum(Number) AS [Total Number]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY IIf(Sex1 < Sex2, Sex1, Sex2),
         IIf(Sex1 < Sex2, Sex2, Sex1) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION query to force the Sex1/Sex2 pairs to be in the same order

```sql
    SELECT 
        Nz(Sex1, "") & Nz(Sex2, "") AS Sex,
        Number
    FROM TableName
    WHERE Nz(Sex1, "") >= Nz(Sex2, "")
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        Nz(Sex2, "") & Nz(Sex1, "") AS Sex,
        Number
    FROM TableName
    WHERE Nz(Sex1, "") < Nz(Sex2, "")
```

producing

```
Sex  Number
---  ------
FF        3
MF        1
FF        9
MM        3
F         5
M         8
MF        5
MF        2
```

and then use that as a subquery to produce the totals

```sql
SELECT
    Sex,
    SUM(Number) AS [Total Number]
FROM
    (
            SELECT 
                Nz(Sex1, "") & Nz(Sex2, "") AS Sex,
                Number
            FROM TableName
            WHERE Nz(Sex1, "") >= Nz(Sex2, "")
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                Nz(Sex2, "") & Nz(Sex1, "") AS Sex,
                Number
            FROM TableName
            WHERE Nz(Sex1, "") < Nz(Sex2, "")
    )
GROUP BY Sex
```

producing

```
Sex  Total Number
---  ------------
F               5
FF             12
M               8
MF              8
MM              3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using CONCAT() function in MSSQL to get 2 columns in one.

SELECT CONCAT(`Sex1`,`Sex2`) AS Sex, Sum(`Number`) AS `Total_Number` FROM `db`.`test` GROUP BY concat(`Sex1`,`Sex2`);

Comment: Does Access have a `CONCAT()` function? Even if it did, the `group by` you have would not solve the issue asked. MF would be grouped separately from FM.